# Creating procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to build a procedure that i would use to check my data format before processing it to the net stop and i need this procedure to check the format of my file. So what i need is, my database to use a specific folder and then check the data thats loaded into the table. 
How can I get it work, any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cannot reach outside itself to do anything with files.

Checking/cleansing incoming data is best done in your client language (PHP, Java, VB, ...)